# How to free all allocated memory by a component

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, sparse-matrix

I have a component to implement sparse matrix in c++, however as I checked its implementation, some memory allocations are not deallocated correctly. I have access to the source code, but it's somehow complicated and I prefer not to change it. It's strange for me that some simple functions such as printf and fopen have memory leaks as deleaker shows!!

I have a question:

1. Is there any way I can free all the memory spaces a component allocated externally?

Thanks

Comment: If you have two different questions, you should post two questions. Otherwise you will get a lot of answers that address one part of the question, but not the other (like mine). You should also consider accepting more answers, this gives people more incentive to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. That depends on the code. In order to free a chunk of memory, you need the pointer that was returned by the function allocating it. It might be that this pointer is not accessible to you from the outside. For example, consider your class has a function like this:

   ```
   void func() {
       int * ptr = new int[1024];
   }
   ```

   It is impossible to free that memory once this function has returned, because the pointer returned by `new` is lost.
2. Cannot help you there.

Comment: I made a simple change in source code where in each allocation, I save the address and in the destructor, I release them. But I think there are some (advanced) way to make the process automatic, in the same way as [deleaker](http://www.deleaker.com) works (I think they have changed the new function!!)